# A:hover activates when it's not supposed to

Tags: css, html, hyperlink, hover

I have this kind of complex set up with divs and links. Anyway, the logo in the top of left of my page is supposed to change when you hover over it, and it does. However, it also changes if your mouse goes anywhere in the top section of the page (outlined in red on the image)

Also when I click on the logo, the link doesn't work. I think it may have to do with the way I have the divs set up, but i'm not sure.

I'm still kind of new at all of this, and I'm a little overwhelmed at figuring out this issue. If you can help, I would appreciate it.

Below is my html, css, and an image to help show you what I'm talking about.

[image]

This is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Playing with backgrounds</title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">

<div id="topheader"> 

<a href="index.html">
<div id="logo">
<div id="navigation">
<a href="index.html">NEWS</a><br />
<a href="index.html">ABOUT</a><br />
<a href="index.html">VOLUNTEER</a><br />
<a href="index.html">DONATE</a><br />
<a href="index.html">CONTACT US</a>
</div>
</div>
</a>
</div>


<div id="welcome">
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<h2>
To 
<span class="gold"> Promise Land Partners</span></h2>

</div>


<div id="bottom_bar">
<p>COPYRIGHT DAVIDMORRIS © 2014 | <a href="index.html">NEWSLETTER</a> | <a href="index.html">FACEBOOK</a>
<span class="right">DESIGN: HANGING OUT</span>
</p>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my CSS

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
    background-image: url(img/dot.png), url(img/background.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat, no-repeat;
    background-position: top left, center center fixed;
    background-size: auto, cover;;
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

#topheader {
    height: 135px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    background-image: url(img/headerbar.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

#logo {
    background-image:url(img/PLP.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top left;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#logo:hover, #logo:active {
    background-image:url(img/PLP_pushed.png);
}

#navigation {
    background-image: none;
    background-position: top left;
    padding-left: 180px;
}

#bottom_bar {
    background-image:url(img/bottom_bar.jpg);
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 27px;
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
}

#bottom_bar p {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 0;
}

.right {
    float:right;
}

#welcome {
    background-image: url(img/welcomepanel.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    top: 70px;
    height: 261px;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding_left: 10px;
    margin: 0;
}

h1 {
    color:white;
    padding-left: 90px;
    font-size: 6em;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 8px;
}

h2 {
    color: white;
    font-size: 4em;
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: .65em;
}

.gold {
    color: #ee9f00;
    font-size: .75em;
    margin: 0;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

a:visited {
    color: #c88601;
}

a:focus {
    color: #ee9f00;
}

a:hover {
    color: #ee9f00;
}

a:active {
    color: c88601;
}

#navigation a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

#navigation a:visited {
    color: white;
}

#navigation a:focus {
    background-color: #ee9f00;
}

#navigation a:hover {
    background-color: #ee9f00;
}

#navigation a:active {
    background-color: #ee9f00;
}
```

Comment: Not surprising given the width of the #logo is 100%. You need to break out the real logo into it's own div

Comment: You should only show the relevant parts of your code when you are asking a question. Best would be to try to reproduce the problem with the minimal amount of code, stripping out everything that does not affect it. This way, 95% of the time you find the problem yourself, and in the remaining cases, you can post relevant code, not wasting other people's time. I know you are a beginner, but you should learn this the sooner the better.

Comment: Kapa, thanks for the tip. I only did it this time, because last time someone said I didn't post enough of my css. They said to post the whole thing so they could do a jsfiddle. But I'll only show the relevant code next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your CSS set to change the image when you hover over `#logo` and `#logo` is set to `width: 100%;` Try changing the width of `#logo` or, if that breaks your style, add a child `div` to `#logo` in which you can change the background image.

See this fiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/QDgVy/

HTML

```
<a href="index.html">
    <div id="logo_container">
    <div id="logo"></div>
        <div id="navigation">
            <a href="index.html">NEWS</a><br />
            <a href="index.html">ABOUT</a><br />
            <a href="index.html">VOLUNTEER</a><br />
            <a href="index.html">DONATE</a><br />
            <a href="index.html">CONTACT US</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

CSS

```
#logo_container {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top left;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: black;
}
#logo {
    background-image:url(...);
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
#logo:hover, #logo:active {
    background-image:url(... );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Your suggestions helped me solve it. I ended up changing the #topheader into my container and put the link around the logo, then taking it's width down to the size of the image. That fixed it. Thank you.